# Why aiohttp works slower than requests wrapped by run_in_executor?

Tags: python, python-requests, aiohttp, python-asyncio

all!

I need to make about 10,000 requests to the web service, and i expected JSON in response. Since the requests are independent of each other, I want to run them in parallel. I think `aiohttp` can help me with that. I wrote the following code:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def execute_module(session: aiohttp.ClientSession, module_id: str,
                         post_body: dict) -> dict:
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': r'application/json',
        'Authorization': fr'Bearer {TOKEN}',
    }

    async with session.post(
            fr'{URL}/{module_id}/steps/execute',
            headers=headers,
            json=post_body,
    ) as response:
        return await response.json()


async def execute_all(campaign_ids, post_body):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        return await asyncio.gather(*[
            execute_module(session, campaign_id, post_body)
            for campaign_id in campaign_ids
        ])

campaign_ids = ['101', '102', '103'] * 400
post_body = {'inputs': [{"name": "one", "value": 1}]}

print(asyncio.run(execute_all(campaign_ids, post_body)))
```

**P.S.** I make 1,200 requests for testing.

Another way to solve it - wrapped `requests.post` in `run_in_executor` function. I know it's wrong to use blocking code in the asynchronous function, **but it works faster** (~ 7 seconds vs. ~ 10 seconds for aiohttp)

```
import requests
import asyncio


def execute_module(module_id, post_body):
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': r'application/json',
        'Authorization': fr'Bearer {TOKEN}',
    }

    return requests.post(
        fr'{URL}/{module_id}/steps/execute',
        headers=headers,
        json=post_body,
    ).json()

async def execute_all(campaign_ids, post_body):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    return await asyncio.gather(*[
        loop.run_in_executor(None, execute_module, campaign_id, post_body)
        for campaign_id in campaign_ids
    ])

campaign_ids = ['101', '102', '103'] * 400
post_body = {'inputs': [{"name": "one", "value": 1}]}

print(asyncio.run(execute_all(campaign_ids, post_body)))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uvloop -  https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop? This should increase speed of aiohttp request

Comment: This in no way addresses the question

Answer (score 0):

`loop.run_in_executor(None, ...)` runs syncroneous code in a thread pool (multiple threads). Event loop runs code in one thread.
My guess is that waiting for IO shouldn't make much of a difference, but handling the response (i.e. json decoding) does.

Answer (score 0):

It probably due to `def execute_module` calls don't share `requests.Session`, i.e. each has its connection pool
https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/requests/sessions.py#L831
https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/requests/adapters.py#L138

On the other hand, `async def execute_module` runs with shared `aiohttp.ClientSession`, having limit of 100 connections https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/latest/http_request_lifecycle.html#how-to-use-the-clientsession

To check that, it may pass a customised `aiohttp.TCPConnector` to `aiohttp.ClientSession` with larger limit:

- https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/latest/http_request_lifecycle.html#how-to-use-the-clientsession
- https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/latest/client_advanced.html#limiting-connection-pool-size